# Export calendar events to google calendar, ical, microsoft outlook

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-api, icalendar, microsoft-sync-framework

I have used jquery calendar, and I have used to create event details, now I want to export the same event details to google calendar,iCal and also Microsoft outlook, depending upon the user requirements.But I want to procvide this 3 features. Is there any tools already available or I have to dirty my hands to code the whole thing myself.

FYI:I have used servlets and MySQL at the back end and jquery along with HTML5 at the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using java on server side, you can use the [iCal4j](https://github.com/ical4j) library for creating iCalender.

Basically, you need only iCal for completing your requirement. Google, Microsoft, Apple and many others like Mozilla Sunbird support iCalender so you can just use one format, rather than going with different formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution, actually when I user clicks on the export link I have to display all the 3 features he can sync with any of the calenders, so is there any libraries available or plugins.

Comment: did you go thru the examples provided on the site? http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Examples

Comment: ya I went through the tutorial, I want some thing which is very similar to this (have a look at this site http://compute2011.doattend.com/) in the right hand side of the broswer u can observe "Add this to your calendar" module, I want build the same part, can you please help me out